# Passport JS - One Login Form - Redirect to Different URI's Depended on User Role

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using Passport JS to handle authentication and Express JS to handle my routing.

Currently, I have a login route that on success go to the `/teacher` URI. (As shown below).

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect: '/teacher', // redirect to the teacher profile section
        failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the login page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    }));
```

I have three main parts of my application, ***Teacher, Parent, Student***.

I have built the ***Teacher*** side of the application but now looking to build the Student and Parent,

In my Passport JS session I have `req.user.group` which tells me if the user is a Teacher, Parent or Student.

Is there any way of redirecting to different locations dependent on what type of user logs onto the application.

E.G If a parent was to log on it would go to `/parent` and a student `/student`

Thank you.

Comment: what does your `req.user.group` contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.status(401).json(error);
    if (!user) return res.status(404).json({message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});

    else {
        if(req.user.group==='Teacher'){
            res.redirect('/teacher');
        }
        else if(req.user.group==='Parent'){
            res.redirect('/parent');
        }
        else{
            res.redirect('/student');
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: I get an error message stating 'req is not defined' on my node server?